# ParserError: Expected identifier but got '(' --> contracts/buy.sol:4:11:

Tags: solidity

solidity issues
ParserError: Expected identifier but got '('
--> contracts/buy.sol:4:11:

contract myContract{
maping(address => uint256) public balances;

```
address payable wallet;
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace *maping* with `mapping`.

NOTE: For declare a mapping you must to use `mapping` keyword!